# Making My Cache Work and Not Theirs: Blacklist for Blocking Caching Sites with Squidguard?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, blacklist, squid

Is there a Squid Guard blacklist (assuming SSL decryption and inspection) that will block caching websites like Google Cache, Google Translate, and the Internet Wayback Machine?

Comment: @Jedi I think you are misunderstanding the question; I want to block users, not robots.